# How to create a condition in the HTML using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this object

```
people = [{name: "John", registered: true },{name: "Micky", registered: false },{name: "Carol", registered: true }]
```

and I have this angular HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="person in people">
    {{person.name}}
    <div class="already-registered-icon">&nbsp;</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**My question is - how do I make a condition to display the registered icon only when the user is already registered?**

I would think of something like this (but I don't know how it can be written):

```
{{if person.registered}}
        <div class="already-registered-icon">&nbsp;</div>
{{end}}
```

Comment: Check the docs. But if you want to go on guessing, I'd go for `#if`.

Comment: The [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [ngShow](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow):

```
<div ng-show="person.registered" class="already-registered-icon">&nbsp;</div>
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/usodaw/1/

Comment: this solves my issue (assigning display:none) but is there an attribute that will not render the HTML itself at all if the condition is true?

Comment: @Alon I don't know a build-in solution. You could probably write your own directive, though. But I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

It was the `ng-show` attribute I was missing

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="person in people">
    {{person.name}}
    <div ng-show="person.registered" class="already-registered-icon">&nbsp;</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```